# How do you compare a textfield value inside the textfield?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, textfield

I have recently been learning to code Swift, using xCode. I have created a simple storyboard and am trying to compare a textfield value, inside the textfield.

Here is my code:

```
var numberone = 0
var numbertwo = 0
var answerstring :String = ""
var answerint :Int = 0
var userInput :String = ""

@IBAction func userTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {

    numberone = randomInt(min: 1, max: 9)
    numbertwo = randomInt(min: 1, max: 9)
    questionLabel.text = "\(numberone) + \(numbertwo)"
    answerint = numberone + numbertwo
    answerstring = "\(answerint)"
    if  userTextField.text! = "\(answerstring)" {
        questionResponse.text! = "Correct!"
    } else {
        questionResponse.text! = "Incorrect. The answer was \(answerint)."
    }
```

The error is on the **userTextField.text!**, and it says:
 `Value of type '(UITextField) -> ()' has no member 'text'`

Comment: `userTextField` is a *function* (or *method*). `sender` is the (reference to the) text field ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing `userTextField` which is the method name, it should be `sender` instead:

```
@IBAction func userTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    numberone = randomInt(min: 1, max: 9)
    numbertwo = randomInt(min: 1, max: 9)
    questionLabel.text = "\(numberone) + \(numbertwo)"
    answerint = numberone + numbertwo
    answerstring = "\(answerint)"
    // here is the change, 'sender' instead of 'userTextField':
    if  sender.text! = "\(answerstring)" {
        questionResponse.text! = "Correct!"
    } else {
        questionResponse.text! = "Incorrect. The answer was \(answerint)."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the textfield from the sender you receive on you @IBAction.

It's very simple. The sender is the textfield you want.

First:

```
    if sender.text! == "\(yourVariable)" {
        //do something
    }else{
        //do someting
    }
```

remember to use double equals to compare. If you use only one it will set the value of the textfield.